# Flink Session Cluster vs Job Cluster

Tags: apache-flink

Please can some one help me on this to under stand better

How to create Flink Session based cluster and How to create job based cluster? Do we have  any specific configuration params?

How de we know cluster is session based or job based?

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in the Flink documentation. For an overview, see https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/deployment/overview/, and for the details, see the pages for your specific environment, for example:

- [standalone](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/overview/)
- [standalone kubernetes](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/kubernetes/)
- [native kubernetes](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/deployment/resource-providers/native_kubernetes/)
- [yarn](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/deployment/resource-providers/yarn/)

Note that job mode deployments have been deprecated in favor of application mode.